# Spark - How to combine/merge elements in Dataframe which are in Seq[Row] to generate a Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to start by saying I am forced to use Spark 1.6

I am generating a `DataFrame` from a JSON file like this:

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"},
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"},
{"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "28"},
{"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"},
{"id" : "1205", "name" : "mendy", "age" : "25"},
{"id" : "1206", "name" : "rob", "age" : "24"},
{"id" : "1207", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
```

The `DataFrame` looks like:

```
+---+----+-------+
|age|  id|   name|
+---+----+-------+
| 25|1201| satish|
| 28|1202|krishna|
| 28|1203|  amith|
| 23|1204|  javed|
| 25|1205|  mendy|
| 24|1206|    rob|
| 23|1207| prudvi|
+---+----+-------+
```

What I do with this `DataFrame` is to group by age, order by id and filter all age group with more than 1 student. I use the following script:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sqlContext.read.json("students.json")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val arrLen = udf {a: Seq[Row] => a.length > 1 }

val mergedDF = df.withColumn("newCol", collect_set(struct("age","id","name")).over(Window.partitionBy("age").orderBy("id"))).select("newCol","age")

val filterd = mergedDF.filter(arrLen(col("newCol")))
```

And now the current result is:

```
[WrappedArray([28,1203,amith], [28,1202,krishna]),28]
[WrappedArray([25,1201,satish], [25,1205,mendy]),25]
[WrappedArray([23,1204,javed], [23,1207,prudvi]),23]
```

What I want now is to merge those two students rows inside the `WrappedArray` into one, taking for example the `id` of the first student and the `name` of the second student.

To achieve that I wrote the following function:

```
def PrintOne(List : Seq[Row], age : String):Row  ={ 
      val studentsDetails = Array(age, List(0).getAs[String]("id"), List(1).getAs[String]("name")) 
      val mergedStudent= new GenericRowWithSchema(studentsDetails .toArray,List(0).schema)

      mergedStudent
    }
```

I know this function do the trick, because when I test it using a foreach it prints out the expected values:

```
filterd.foreach{x => val student = PrintOne(x.getAs[Seq[Row]](0), x.getAs[String]("age"))
                         println("merged student: "+student)
                   }
```

OutPut:

```
merged student: [28,1203,krishna]
merged student: [23,1204,prudvi]
merged student: [25,1201,mendy]
```

But when I try to do the same inside a map to collect the returned values the problems begin.

If I run without encoder:

```
val merged = filterd.map{row => (row.getAs[String]("age") , PrintOne(row.getAs[Seq[Row]](0), row.getAs[String]("age")))}
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No
>   Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
>   - field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_2")
>   - root class: "scala.Tuple2"

And when I try to generate an `Econder` on my own, I fail as well:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
    implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(filterd.schema)

    val merged = filterd.map{row => (row.getAs[String]("age") , PrintOne(row.getAs[Seq[Row]](0), row.getAs[String]("age")))}(encoder)
```

> type mismatch; found :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
>   required: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[(String,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row)]

How can I provide the correct encoder or even better, avoid it?

I have been told to avoid using map + a custom function, but the logic I need to apply is more complex than just pick up one field from each row. It will be more to combine fields from several, checking the order of the rows and if the values are null or not. And as far as I know just by using a custom function I can solve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from the `map` is of type `(String, Row)` therefore it cannot be encoded using `RowEncoder` alone. You have to provide matching tuple encoder:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

val encoder = Encoders.tuple(
  Encoders.STRING,
  RowEncoder(
    // The same as df.schema in your case
    StructType(Seq(
      StructField("age", StringType), 
      StructField("id", StringType),
      StructField("name", StringType)))))

filterd.map{row => (
  row.getAs[String]("age"),
  PrintOne(row.getAs[Seq[Row]](0), row.getAs[String]("age")))
}(encoder)
```

Overall this approach looks like an anti-pattern. If you want to use more functional style you should avoid `Dataset[Row]`:

```
case class Person(age: String, id: String, name: String)

filterd.as[(Seq[Person], String)].map { 
  case (people, age)  => (age, (age, people(0).id, people(1).name))
}
```

or `udf`.

Also please note that `o.a.s.sql.catalyst` package, including `GenericRowWithSchema`, is intended mostly for internal usage. Unless necessary otherwise, prefer `o.a.s.sql.Row`.